# ARIMA parameters

Tags: arima

In most examples I find ARIMA parameters (p, d, q) to be very small, often 1 or 2.

Is that in practice enough (for p and q especially), or higher values are used, like 10 or 100?

I have found a method to automatically estimate these values using AIC as criteria, but not sure for what range of values to specify.

I should emphasize that I'm working on a Python solution, so automatic parameter detection in R is not an option.

Additionally, I'm also interested in same thing with Seasonal ARIMA.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [forecast](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=forecast) package for R by [Rob J. Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/) and its `auto.arima` function. The package is described in the paper [*Automatic Time Series Forecasting: The forecast Package for R*](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v027i03). It uses the following defaults

```
max.p = 5, max.q = 5, max.P = 2, max.Q = 2, max.order = 5, max.d = 2,
max.D = 1, start.p = 2, start.q = 2, start.P = 1, start.Q = 1
```

Since the package implements what you are trying to do (and does it *very* well), it would be worth checking.